# Multi language testing?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

We have the web application in 20 different languages, for which we’re planning to use the same recorded script. But the play back is not working for any other language other than one recorded. This is because the text captions are different when compared to the one recorded. How can I do this tests?Thanks (I have been using Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: Can't you use culture (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.71%29.aspx) for your tests such the same script would load different test resources for different language? If you already use culture variant resources for your web application to support different languages, it should be easy.

Comment: We already use culture for different languages and we have resx files. How can I do? Could you please an example script?

Comment: Well, it all depends on the way your script works (which you give no info about). But basically the script should load a resource file specific to the culture that contains the text captions / expected values for that specific language.